# How to hide <div> element from indexing by Google?

Tags: html, google-search-console, google-index

I have such a component that I need to hide from Google indexing, but this component is used on every page of the site.

```
const SmallCompaniesBlock = ({code, price, exchange, changes, beta}) => {
  return (
    <div className={styles["companies-item"]}>
      <div className={styles["item-code"]}>{code}</div>
      <div className={styles["item-wrapper"]}>
        <div className={styles["price-per-stock"]}>{price}$</div>
        <div className={styles["stock-exchange"]}>{exchange}</div>
      </div>
      <div className={styles["item-wrapper"]}>
        <div className={styles["stock-percent"]}>+0,10%</div>
        <div className={styles["stock-increase"]}>+128,6$</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

I tried the following options:

- data-nosnippet="true"

```
<div className={styles["companies-item"]} data-nosnippet="true">
     ....
</div>
```

- noindex tag

```
<noindex>
    <div className={styles["companies-item"]} data-nosnippet="true">
         ....
    </div>
</noindex> // but this only for bad browsers
```

Comment: Do you need to be copyable? Is using images in place of numbers good enough?

Comment: This might qualify as "programming" and get an answer here, but this question has already been asked and answered at Webmasters: [Preventing robots from crawling specific part of a page](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/16390/preventing-robots-from-crawling-specific-part-of-a-page)